# Disable Logging for Akka STM (Multiverse)

Tags: scala, logging, akka, stm

I am using [akka stm](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/scala/stm.html) and when my application starts it prints out (to the stderr):

```
Okt 20, 2011 10:17:10 AM org.multiverse.api.GlobalStmInstance <clinit>
Information: Initializing GlobalStmInstance using factoryMethod 'org.multiverse.stms.alpha.AlphaStm.createFast'.
Okt 20, 2011 10:17:10 AM org.multiverse.stms.alpha.AlphaStm <init>
Information: Created a new AlphaStm instance
Okt 20, 2011 10:17:10 AM org.multiverse.api.GlobalStmInstance <clinit>
Information: Successfully initialized GlobalStmInstance using factoryMethod 'org.multiverse.stms.alpha.AlphaStm.createFast'.
```

How can I disable it (logging)?

Comment: A related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499858/set-logging-level-in-akka may be helpful.

Comment: @DonRoby Thx, I know that question (searched before), but with that `logback.xml` and `akka.conf` debug level `ERROR` the above still appears. Seems to me that `org.multiverse._` is using a logger too.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm sure there is a better solution via config xml files, this is a quick fix which worked for me:

```
import java.util.logging.{Logger, Level}

object DisableLogging { 
  Logger.getLogger("org.multiverse.api.GlobalStmInstance").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  Logger.getLogger("org.multiverse.stms.alpha.AlphaStm").setLevel(Level.OFF)
}
```